# ORA-01722:Invalid Number for Numeric Datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute the query:

```
UPDATE USER SET ATTEMPTS = ATTEMPTS + 1 WHERE  USER_ID = "abc"
```

here ATTEMPTS is Numeric datatype
But I am receiving the error `ORA-01722:Invalid Number`

Comment: What is the data type of `USER_ID`?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes. `"abc"` is a column name, `'abc'` is a string literal. But assuming tha `user_id` is a number, then neither of them make sense.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably two things going on. user_id is numeric and in your post, you did not copy paste the offending sql statement, but replaced `'abc'` with `"abc"`.

The following snippet reproduces your error, and it is caused not by `attempts` not being numeric, but rather by user_id being numeric and compared to a string:

```
create table tq84_n (
  attempts number,
  user_id  number
);

insert into tq84_n values (1, 1);

update tq84_n set attempts = attempts + 1 where user_id = 'abc';

drop table tq84_n purge;
```